# Killing function after specified period of time

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am running some banner ads with some pretty strict size restrictions, so I've gone with an ultra simple slideshow with Javascript and CSS. I'm trying to kill the automatic slideshow after a period of time, but can't seem to work it out.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var stage = document.getElementById("stage");
    var fadeComplete = function(e) { stage.appendChild(arr[0]); };
    var arr = stage.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].addEventListener("animationend", fadeComplete, false);
    }
}, false);
```

How would I go about simply killing this function after 15 seconds so it just ceases to do anything?

Just an edit, I've added a setTimeout to the function but it doesn't seem to be working.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function slideshow(e) {
    var stage = document.getElementById("stage");
    var fadeComplete = function(e) { stage.appendChild(arr[0]); };
    var arr = stage.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].addEventListener("animationend", fadeComplete, false);
    }
    }, false);
    setTimeout(slideshow, 2000);
```

And here is another attempt at wrapping setTimeOut over the eventListener which seems to kill the script entirely at 0 seconds:

```js
setTimeout(()=> window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var stage = document.getElementById("stage");
    var fadeComplete = function(e) { stage.appendChild(arr[0]); };
    var arr = stage.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].addEventListener("animationend", fadeComplete, false);
    }
  }, false), 10000);
```

Comment: You can use `setTimeout`.

Comment: I updated my question using the setTimeout but it seems to be ignored and not working.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a `setTimeout` around a `window.removeEventListener(...)` outta do the trick!

```
setTimeout(()=> window.removeEventListener(...), 1500);
```

Note: `setTimeout` executes a function, once, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds

Comment: I updated my question using your solution, but it seems to kill/break the script entirely with no console errors.